# Convert dictionary key and values into to separate lists?

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I convert a dictionary which contains key:pair values such as {Hello:3, Bye:4}, into two different lists? One for the keys and one for the values?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the keys and values methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dictionary `keys` and `values` methods:

```
my_dict={"key_a":"value_a","key_b":"value_b"}

print(list(my_dict.keys()))
print(list(my_dict.values()))
```

**Output**

```
['key_a', 'key_b']
['value_a', 'value_b']
```